# Common jQuery insecure programming

Tags: jquery, security

I am writing some purely client-side jQuery (no AJAX). Should I be aware of jQuery-specific security holes I might inadvertently introduce for the clients?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. jQuery is just a middleware, it sits on the API of the browser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a library to make native JavaScript much easier to use. The only security holes it will have are the ones introduced by the browser to *any* JavaScript code. These holes aren't that common, but *they're* the ones you need to look out for. The only thing jQuery might contribute is a few bugs, but it's tested thoroughly on all common browsers.